# how to insert in the table when we want to insert while concerning about tables id

Tags: mysql, database

How to insert in the table when we want to insert while concerning about tables id. Here my id is the primary key

I got the following error while running the query operation failed:

> There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>   Executing:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `abc`.`hhghgh` (`column1`, `column2`) 
> VALUES ('df', 'ddfddf') where id =1;
> ```
>
> ERROR 1064: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'where id =1' at line 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`hhghgh` (`column1`, `column2`) 
VALUES ('df', 'ddfddf') where id = 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is the id field is auto increment ?

Comment: You can't use WHERE for an INSERT statement. You would use that with an UPDATE statement.

Comment: It is not about what you can't do, it is about why would you and what did you expect.

Comment: Use `INSERT` without `WHERE` or `UPDATE` with `WHERE`. `WHERE` is always related to existing records and a record that gets newly inserted doesn't exist.

Comment: yes id field id auto increment

Comment: first i insert the values of column1 for example my column has two values ,the next i try to insert the values in column two but because i does not refer to the particular id every time a new row is created

Answer (score 2):

Check out the MySQL manual for the [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). You will notice that there is no WHERE clause. Because basically it doesn't make any sense in the context of an INSERT.

So either you want to INSERT and specify the id, which would look like:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`hhghgh` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`) 
VALUES (1, 'df', 'ddfddf');
```

Or you want to [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) the current entry with id=1 whch would be

```
UPDATE `abc`.`hhghgh` SET column1 = 'df', SET column2 = 'ddfddf'
WHERE id=1;
```

Or if id is AUTO_INCREMENT and you just want to insert a new record (I don't think this is what you want but for the sake of completeness):

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`hhghgh` (`column1`, `column2`) 
VALUES ('df', 'ddfddf')
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you could use WHERE with INSERT , u could use UPDATE query

> UPDATE `abc`.`hhghgh` SET `column1`="df", `column2`="ddfddf"
>                     where `id` =1;

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` logic as part of the insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`hhghgh` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`) VALUES (1, 'df', 'ddfddf')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column1`='df', `column2`='ddfddf';`
```